# Select all inputs within the form the triggered the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find away to select all inputs within a form using jquery, where the trigger was initiated from. so for example if the button was clicked in form 1 only the inputs from form 1 would be selected, and nothing from form 2 would be selected.

```
<form action="" method="POST">    <!--form 1-->

<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="hidden" value="87678"  />

<input type="button" onclick="doit()" />

</form>




<form action="" method="POST">   <!--form 2-->

<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="hidden" value="87678"  />

<input type="button" onclick="doit()" />

</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "selected"? I see the inputs are all either text or hidden.

Comment: What have you tried? this is a very simple task involving the `$()` method with a context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(':button').on('click', function(){
    var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
    $(form).children().each(function(evt){
        if($(this).attr('type') == 'text'){
            alert(this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

See this [Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DAnbq/2/)

Greetings.

Comment: Won't your code just show the text from all inputs? (it has to only show inputs from the current form)

Comment: parent might be different from form not in the given html of course but then it does look like an example

Answer (score 1):

Use the event target to get to the parent form and the find all inputs in that form

```
function doit(event){
    $(event.target).parent("form").find("input")
}
```

for this to work you will have change your html of the anchor tag to

```
<input type="button" onclick="doit(event)" />
```

Comment: You don't have access to `event` given the current html. (you also don't have access to the clicked element given the current html)

Comment: @KevinB I thought that to be rather obvious since whenever you change the signature of a function for that to take effect you need to change the call but since not all find that obvious I've updated accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){ 
    console.log( $('input',$(this).closest('form')) ) 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kR3ws/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` fields to your buttons and forms.

```
<form id="form1" action="" method="POST">    <!--form 1-->
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="hidden" value="87678"  />
<input id="btn1" type="button" onclick="doit()" />
</form>

<form id="form2" action="" method="POST">   <!--form 2-->
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="hidden" value="87678"  />
<input id="btn2" type="button" onclick="doit()" />
</form>
```

Then declare event like this :

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    var data = $('#form1').serialize();
    alert('form1 : '+data);
});

$('#btn2').click(function(){
    var data = $('#form2').serialize();
    alert('form2 : '+data);
});
```

Comment: cumbersome when you can simply use `$(this)` or `event.target` and then just use the same handler for all buttons

Comment: Of course you are right and your answer is better than mine (+1 BTW). But I don't want to copy. My answer is the dumbest way to achieve the asker target and it is sometimes easier to understand for newbie.